# How can I run arbitrary commands as part of a deb package install?

Tags: ppa, packaging, development

I'm creating a ppa deb package for a python module, replacing a pip package (which I also created), and I would like to run "pip uninstall" as part of the deb installation.

How can I run "pip uninstall" as part of the ppa package install?

I want to do this because the pip install in /usr/local/lib takes priority over the deb install in /usr/lib, so users who previously installed with pip could unintentionally be using the old pip version when they install the deb version.

---

I tried two things already, neither of which worked and I don't know why (any suggestions for how to troubleshoot this better would be greatly appreciated -- I tried "dpkg --log=log.txt -i " but the log didn't show any pip uninstall error messages):

A. execute pip uninstall in setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.install import install

import os.path
import subprocess

class CustomInstallCommand(install):
    def run(self):
        if os.path.exists("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bamliquidatorbatch"): 
            print "Old pip bamliquidatorbatch install detected, attempting to remove"
            subprocess.call(["pip", "uninstall", "-y", "BamLiquidatorBatch"])

        install.run(self)

setup(
    ...
    cmdclass={
        'install': CustomInstallCommand,
    }
)
```

This worked fine when installed with "sudo python setup.py install" but pip uninstall never ran when the package was installed with "dpkg -i".

B. execute pip uninstall in rules makefile

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

%:
    dh $@ --with python2 --buildsystem=python_distutils
    if [ -d "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bamliquidatorbatch" ]; then pip uninstall -y BamLiquidatorBatch; echo; fi
```

When I ran similar code in a makefile directly, it worked fine, but again pip uninstall never ran when the package was installed with "dpkg -i".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if it's not really recommended to remove silently a package in `/usr/local` you could do it in a `debian/bamliquidatorbatch.preinst` script:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

if [ -d "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bamliquidatorbatch" ]; then
    pip uninstall -y BamLiquidatorBatch;
fi
```

Note that `bamliquidatorbatch` should be the exact name of your debian binary package (to match `debian/bamliquidatorbatch.preinst`).

Comment: Thanks, that worked great!  I had to name the file  python-bamliquidatorbatch.preinst to match my package name.  I realize that this probably isn't generally good practice, but I don't want a bunch of people to waste time troubleshooting why they are using an old version by accident, and as the author of the old pip package I think I have the right to uninstall it when someone upgrades to the new deb package :)

Comment: Probably a generally approach would be to just exit 1 in preinst if the pip version is present.  Just noting this option for others that might read this answer (I actually am going to pip uninstall though).

Comment: @JDiMatteo use `debconf` to ask users if they want the old version removed. That's the right way to go about it.